# How to create a document with user 'uid' in Firebase firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a document with an id that of the user as he signs up

this is the function which runs when user signs up ->

```
const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((auth) => {
        if (auth) {
          db.collection("users").add({
            email: email,
            password: password,
          });

          history.push("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

Can anyone help me with how do I pass the .doc reference to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Could you try the following code?

```
const register = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(credential => {
      if (credential && credential.user) {
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(credential.user.uid)
          .set({
            email: email,
            password: password
          });

        history.push("/");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error.message));
};
```

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential

Comment: How do I access this uid to use it in a different component? Like if I had to add something in the database specific to the current user?

Comment: Use `onAuthStateChanged()` and manage state `user` using React Context etc. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Comment: Hi, as it worked, could you accept the answer, so the community has an easier time finding the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
await db
  .collection("users")
  .add({ name: "baibhav", gender: "male" })
  .then(async (docRef) => {
    const ref = db.collection("users").doc(docRef.id)
    ref
      .update({ car: "Ferrari" })
      .then(() => {
        // updated
        console.log("succeed")
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

You'd better use a ".add" method. it makes document id automatically.
and You can use the document id after document fetched.

and toss the docRef.id to that wherever you have to use. and call the update method with the document id.